# Auto login website in GeckoFX [C#]

Tags: gecko, autologin

I want some code source to login automatically in website

example:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("Value", textBox2.Text);
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("Value", textBox3.Text);
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login").Invokemember("Click");
```

I want To Gecko

Answer (score 0):

```
        GeckoInputElement Username = new GeckoInputElement(geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByName("username")[0].DomObject);
        Username.Value = textBox2.Text;
        GeckoInputElement Password = new GeckoInputElement(geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByName("password")[0].DomObject);
        Password.Value = textBox3.Text;
        GeckoInputElement login = new GeckoInputElement(geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByName("login")[0].DomObject);
        login.Click();
```